# How to use MMenu.JS in Angular CLI project?

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular CLI project, the MMenu.JS library is malfunctioning.

Live project: [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1gc9sw)

Below is a clip from the error:
[image: Animation clip]

Comment: Help me, please?

Comment: How to fix this error?

Comment: I can't actually *see* anything in the animation. There is a yellow cursor-like object moving around, various menus flash on and off, and there is some unreadable text. I doubt anything can make much of this. In any case, though, it's definitely not a *Git* issue, since Git isn't some fancy animated screen thingy, so I snipped the Git tag.